# Cannot proceed with installation of Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 17.04 from usb, but I'm stuck on this screen

[image: view screenshot]

How can I fix it?

I am on Asrock UEFI?

Comment: You need to boot with `nomodeset` and install Nvidia drivers after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this should be flagged as a duplicate if the solution is on a different **StackExchange** site, but this posted solution should help: https://superuser.com/questions/1200994/no-sprom-available-error-when-installing-ubuntu-from-usb

> To fix this I first disable the WLAN module from bios then proceeded to add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line in the GNU kernel. This allowed me to boot into the test mode and install from there. Once this had been done I was able to install the drivers from the Additional Drivers application.